# JavaScript JPEG mask selective image compression

Tags: javascript, imagemagick, jpeg, fireworks

Adobe Fireworks allowed variable JPEG quality in masked regions, [like this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/web-design-in/0596009879/ch30s05s05.html) or [this](https://bignerdranch.com/blog/image-optimization-with-adobe-fireworks/). Is this optimization available, specifically within the context of JavaScript on the front-end? I would like to know of a library, API, or custom encoding technique that does (or could) output the result. I admit the novelty was lost long ago, and JPEG2000/WebP is new, and there may be patent issues. There seems to be no discussion recently within a modern web context.

---

Edit 1: [Here is an example](https://codepen.io/hex2bin/pen/ycjxn) of per-pixel image encoding. It would require a deeper understanding on my part of the JPEG format (compression). Unless there was a known technique, hence the question. Is the best routine to apply [mask quadtree](https://codepen.io/hex2bin/pen/lIgaB) to RGB image and blur?

```
function getLittleEndianHex(value) {
  var result = [];
  for (var bytes = 4; bytes > 0; bytes--) {
    result.push(String.fromCharCode(value & 255));
    value >>= 8;
  }
  return result.join('');
}

// Set the required bitmap header
var header = 'BM' + getLittleEndianHex(16 * 16) + 
// size of the file (bytes)*
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x36\x00\x00\x00\x28\x00\x00\x00'+ 
getLittleEndianHex(16) + getLittleEndianHex(16) +
// WxH
'\x01\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x0B\x00\x00\x13\x0B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'; 
var W = '\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF';//RGBA
var B = '\x00\x00\x00\xFF';//RGBA
```

---

Edit 2: [I tried the method suggested](https://codepen.io/kpachinger/pen/VwMKoXw) in the comments. Generally, results show no benefit (in file size vs quality) relative to standard `toDataURL()`.

Comment: you'll need to have control over the jpeg encoder. the encoder will need to know per-tile how strongly to quantize. don't expect random libraries to support this, if they just happen to have image I/O capabilities (OpenCV, imagemagick...). you need to deal with jpeg encoder libraries directly, or modify them.

Comment: Did you check that the average client (Edge/Chrome/Firefox) can read such images? AFAIK the patents on JP2000 are no longer active. WebP as no patents (it's used under the hood by ImgUr, for instance). Also, I see many sites save a handful of KB on images, and then deliver them in a page that weights several MB. Image-wise, and javascript foolish, so to speak.It is also possible that  a slight blur of the image outside the area of interest will make a standard JPEG encoder create a smaller image (that will still be compatible with all JPEG decoders).

Comment: thank you, it's just what i always dreamed of!